# css not displaying same between browsers <a> tag

Tags: css

I have a page that displays a number of links. When I view in Chrome I see what I want: links displayed in grey without underlines, and when hovering the link turns black. But when I view in firefox or IE9 all links are eithin in blue or purple and are all underlined. Colour doesn't change when hovering.

What am I doing wrong? Why won't the links display the same in all browsers? I want the links to be the same as they do in chrome.

CSS:

```css
a:link {color: #008000; text-decoration: none} 
a:visited {color: #cccccc; text-decoration: none}
a:active {color: #ff0000; text-decoration: underlined}
a:hover {color: #606060; text-decoration: underlined}
```

My doctype declaration:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" 
"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
```

Comment: Works fine for me in IE9

Comment: [here is a fiddle with your css](http://jsfiddle.net/uLjZX/), does your Firefox display the link in blue/purple or green/gray? For me, it works correctly in Firefox.

Comment: Are you sure that your IE and Firefox are not set to ignore webpages' styles? I'm sorry for this question but sometimes a device does not work because it's not plugged in.

Comment: changed underline links to hover and this solved problem in IE, but text colour still purple. Do you think it's because I'm forcing DNS servers? Am using Google's.

Comment: that's doesn't make sense. As am testing locally. Can't see what I'm doing wrong. How can I find out if IE and firefox are set to ignore web page styles? Surely CSS overrides this???

Comment: The problem is somewhere in the part of the page that was not included in the snippets you included. You can see this by testing your code in a minimal file that contains just the code you posted and the simplest possible link. Then please construct a minimal case that still exhibits the problem and post all the code for it and/or a URL for an uploaded file.

Answer (score 2):

The value `underlined` isn't valid for the property `text-decoration`. You're looking for `underline`.

```
a:link {color: #008000; text-decoration: none;}
a:visited {color: #cccccc; text-decoration: none;}
a:active {color: #ff0000; text-decoration: underline;}
a:hover {color: #606060; text-decoration: underline;}
```

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/MMjqt/)

Comment: This does not explain why the color does not change on Firefox

Comment: have changed but still getting firefox underlining links. Text is in purple. Have also added semi colons. But no change

Comment: @user1022772: What Firefox version do you use? I cannot reproduce this in my Firefox. Also have a look at [Struna's comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10166024/css-not-displaying-same-between-browsers-a-tag/10166053#comment13042360_10166024).

Comment: 11. Do you think it's because I'm forcing DNS servers? Am testing locally. Have read that this can be a potential cause...?